SSSD-AD allowing sshd login without password nor key
When trying to get an Ubuntu 22 joined to our AD domain via SSSD, I have encountered an odd situation where any AD user can login to the system without any password prompt and no ssh-key setup on the host. In the below example USER1 is a sanitized account name with no .ssh directory nor authorized_keys setup on the Ubuntu host.
I believe this is a PAM configuration issue, but I am not sure what specifically in the PAM configs would need to be updated to force a password prompt.
/etc/ssh/sshd_config includes:
HostbasedAuthentication no
IgnoreRhosts yes

PermitEmptyPasswords no
PasswordAuthentication yes

ChallengeResponseAuthentication yes

KerberosAuthentication no

GSSAPIAuthentication no
GSSAPICleanupCredentials no

UsePAM yes

AllowTcpForwarding yes
X11Forwarding no
PermitUserEnvironment no
ClientAliveInterval 900
ClientAliveCountMax 0
UseDNS no
MaxStartups 10:30:100

SSHD debug log output when USER1 logs into the host successfully without any password prompt on the client side.
sshd[157624]: debug1: Forked child 158343.
sshd[158343]: debug1: Set /proc/self/oom_score_adj to 0
sshd[158343]: debug1: rexec start in 4 out 4 newsock 4 pipe 6 sock 7
sshd[158343]: debug1: inetd sockets after dupping: 4, 4
sshd[158343]: Connection from 172.30.128.205 port 64416 on 10.63.129.197 port 22 rdomain ""
sshd[158343]: debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_8.9p1 Ubuntu-3ubuntu0.7
sshd[158343]: debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version OpenSSH_9.7
sshd[158343]: debug1: compat_banner: match: OpenSSH_9.7 pat OpenSSH* compat 0x04000000
sshd[158343]: debug1: permanently_set_uid: 106/65534 [preauth]
sshd[158343]: debug1: list_hostkey_types: rsa-sha2-512,rsa-sha2-256,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ssh-ed25519 [preauth]
sshd[158343]: debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent [preauth]
sshd[158343]: debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received [preauth]
sshd[158343]: debug1: kex: algorithm: curve25519-sha256@libssh.org [preauth]
sshd[158343]: debug1: kex: host key algorithm: ssh-ed25519 [preauth]
sshd[158343]: debug1: kex: client->server cipher: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com MAC: <implicit> compression: none [preauth]
sshd[158343]: debug1: kex: server->client cipher: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com MAC: <implicit> compression: none [preauth]
sshd[158343]: debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_INIT [preauth]
sshd[158343]: debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_INIT received [preauth]
sshd[158343]: debug1: ssh_packet_send2_wrapped: resetting send seqnr 3 [preauth]
sshd[158343]: debug1: rekey out after 134217728 blocks [preauth]
sshd[158343]: debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent [preauth]
sshd[158343]: debug1: Sending SSH2_MSG_EXT_INFO [preauth]
sshd[158343]: debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS [preauth]
sshd[158343]: debug1: ssh_packet_read_poll2: resetting read seqnr 3 [preauth]
sshd[158343]: debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received [preauth]
sshd[158343]: debug1: rekey in after 134217728 blocks [preauth]
sshd[158343]: debug1: KEX done [preauth]
sshd[158343]: debug1: userauth-request for user USER1 service ssh-connection method none [preauth]
sshd[158343]: debug1: attempt 0 failures 0 [preauth]
sshd[158343]: debug1: PAM: initializing for "USER1"
sshd[158343]: debug1: PAM: setting PAM_RHOST to "172.30.128.205"
sshd[158343]: debug1: PAM: setting PAM_TTY to "ssh"
sshd[158343]: debug1: userauth_send_banner: sent [preauth]
sshd[158343]: debug1: userauth-request for user USER1 service ssh-connection method publickey [preauth]
sshd[158343]: debug1: attempt 1 failures 0 [preauth]
sshd[158343]: debug1: userauth_pubkey: publickey test pkalg rsa-sha2-512 pkblob RSA SHA256:IvAkAVaIAXzi48uZEHICHHUVZgYQ5QozSfi/YwvJeUM [preauth]
sshd[158343]: debug1: temporarily_use_uid: 219435810/219400513 (e=0/0)
sshd[158343]: debug1: trying public key file /home/USER1/.ssh/authorized_keys
sshd[158343]: debug1: Could not open authorized keys '/home/USER1/.ssh/authorized_keys': No such file or directory
sshd[158343]: debug1: restore_uid: 0/0
sshd[158343]: Failed publickey for USER1 from 172.30.128.205 port 64416 ssh2: RSA SHA256:IvAkAVaIAXzi48uZEHICHHUVZgYQ5QozSfi/YwvJeUM
sshd[158343]: debug1: userauth-request for user USER1 service ssh-connection method keyboard-interactive [preauth]
sshd[158343]: debug1: attempt 2 failures 1 [preauth]
sshd[158343]: debug1: keyboard-interactive devs  [preauth]
sshd[158343]: debug1: auth2_challenge: user=USER1 devs= [preauth]
sshd[158343]: debug1: kbdint_alloc: devices 'pam' [preauth]
sshd[158343]: debug1: auth2_challenge_start: trying authentication method 'pam' [preauth]
sshd[158345]: debug1: do_pam_account: called
sshd[158345]: pam_access(sshd:account): cannot resolve hostname "cron"
sshd[158345]: pam_access(sshd:account): cannot resolve hostname "crond"
sshd[158345]: pam_faillock(sshd:account): Unknown option: unlock
sshd[158343]: debug1: PAM: num PAM env strings 2
sshd[158343]: Postponed keyboard-interactive for USER1 from 172.30.128.205 port 64416 ssh2 [preauth]
sshd[158343]: debug1: do_pam_account: called
sshd[158343]: Accepted keyboard-interactive/pam for USER1 from 172.30.128.205 port 64416 ssh2
sshd[158343]: debug1: monitor_child_preauth: user USER1 authenticated by privileged process
sshd[158343]: debug1: monitor_read_log: child log fd closed
sshd[158343]: debug1: PAM: establishing credentials
sshd[158343]: pam_unix(sshd:session): session opened for user USER1(uid=219435810) by (uid=0)
systemd-logind[660]: New session 2938 of user USER1.
systemd: pam_faillock(systemd-user:account): Unknown option: unlock
systemd: pam_unix(systemd-user:session): session opened for user USER1(uid=219435810) by (uid=0)
sshd[158343]: User child is on pid 158357
sshd[158357]: debug1: SELinux support disabled
sshd[158357]: debug1: PAM: establishing credentials
sshd[158357]: debug1: permanently_set_uid: 219435810/219400513
sshd[158357]: debug1: rekey in after 134217728 blocks
sshd[158357]: debug1: rekey out after 134217728 blocks
sshd[158357]: debug1: ssh_packet_set_postauth: called
sshd[158357]: debug1: active: key options: agent-forwarding port-forwarding pty user-rc x11-forwarding
sshd[158357]: debug1: Entering interactive session for SSH2.
sshd[158357]: debug1: server_init_dispatch
sshd[158357]: debug1: server_input_channel_open: ctype session rchan 0 win 1048576 max 16384
sshd[158357]: debug1: input_session_request
sshd[158357]: debug1: channel 0: new [server-session]
sshd[158357]: debug1: session_new: session 0
sshd[158357]: debug1: session_open: channel 0
sshd[158357]: debug1: session_open: session 0: link with channel 0
sshd[158357]: debug1: server_input_channel_open: confirm session
sshd[158357]: debug1: server_input_global_request: rtype no-more-sessions@openssh.com want_reply 0
sshd[158357]: debug1: server_input_channel_req: channel 0 request pty-req reply 1
sshd[158357]: debug1: session_by_channel: session 0 channel 0
sshd[158357]: debug1: session_input_channel_req: session 0 req pty-req
sshd[158357]: debug1: Allocating pty.
sshd[158343]: debug1: session_new: session 0
sshd[158343]: debug1: SELinux support disabled
sshd[158357]: debug1: session_pty_req: session 0 alloc /dev/pts/5
sshd[158357]: debug1: Ignoring unsupported tty mode opcode 11 (0xb)
sshd[158357]: debug1: Ignoring unsupported tty mode opcode 17 (0x11)
sshd[158357]: debug1: server_input_channel_req: channel 0 request env reply 0
sshd[158357]: debug1: session_by_channel: session 0 channel 0
sshd[158357]: debug1: session_input_channel_req: session 0 req env
sshd[158357]: debug1: server_input_channel_req: channel 0 request env reply 0

SSSD.conf file contents:
[sssd]
domains = my.domain.com
config_file_version = 2
services = nss, pam
override_space = _
#default_domain_suffix = my.domain.com
domain_resolution_order = my.domain.com
debug_level = 9
full_name_format=%1$s

[nss]
#cache_first = True

[domain/my.domain.com]
#default_shell = /bin/bash
#krb5_store_password_if_offline = True
#cache_credentials = True
#krb5_realm = my.domain.com
#realmd_tags = manages-system joined-with-adcli
#id_provider = ad
#fallback_homedir = /home/%u
#ad_domain = my.domain.com
use_fully_qualified_names = False
ldap_id_mapping = True
access_provider = ad
default_shell = /bin/bash
krb5_store_password_if_offline = True
cache_credentials = True
krb5_realm = my.domain.com
realmd_tags = manages-system joined-with-adcli
id_provider = ad
fallback_homedir = /home/%u
ad_domain = my.domain.com
ad_enabled_domains = my.domain.com
ignore_group_members = True
subdomain_inherit = ignore_group_members
ldap_referrals = False
dyndns_update = false
ad_gpo_access_control = disabled
dyndns_update_ptr = false
ldap_opt_timeout = 20
ldap_network_timeout = 20
dns_resolver_timeout = 20
ad_use_ldaps = false

/etc/pam.d/sshd
# grep -v "#" /etc/pam.d/sshd
@include common-auth
account    required     pam_nologin.so
account  required     pam_access.so
@include common-account
session [success=ok ignore=ignore module_unknown=ignore default=bad]        pam_selinux.so close
session    required     pam_loginuid.so
session    optional     pam_keyinit.so force revoke
@include common-session
session    required     pam_limits.so
session    required     pam_env.so user_readenv=1 envfile=/etc/default/locale
session [success=ok ignore=ignore module_unknown=ignore default=bad]        pam_selinux.so open
@include common-password

common-auth
auth    [default=4 success=ok]          pam_localuser.so
auth    [success=2 default=ignore]  pam_unix.so nullok
auth    [success=1 default=ignore]  pam_sss.so use_first_pass
auth    requisite           pam_deny.so
auth    required            pam_permit.so
auth    optional            pam_cap.so

common-password
password    [success=2 default=ignore]  pam_unix.so obscure yescrypt
password    sufficient          pam_sss.so use_authtok
password    requisite           pam_deny.so
password    required            pam_permit.so

common-account
account [success=1 new_authtok_reqd=done default=ignore]    pam_unix.so
account requisite           pam_deny.so
account required            pam_permit.so
account sufficient          pam_localuser.so
account [default=bad success=ok user_unknown=ignore]    pam_sss.so
account required            pam_faillock.so


You are delegating the authentication/authorization decision to AD aren't you?  When you do that the credentials don't need to be on the local Linux computer.  The ones in AD are sufficient.

I am not sure I know how to verify what you are mentioning here. But either way, what would be the proper way to make the users that login to this host with their AD credentials to be prompted for a password?
I assume it is something to do with the PAM & SSSD configs, but I have not been able to find the right combination to make that possible.

What's in your /etc/pam.d/sshd file and any @include'd files referenced by it (in Debian, Ubuntu, usually the /etc/pam.d/common-* files)? The debug log messages suggest the /etc/security/access.conf (and/or files in /etc/security/access.d/ if any exist) might have some syntax errors too.

@telcoM Added the contents of pam.d/sshd and associated included modules.

The PAM configuration files are processed line by line, so the ordering of the lines (of the same type, i.e. auth, account, session or password) is important.
All the applicable auth lines are in the common-auth file:
auth    [default=4 success=ok]          pam_localuser.so
auth    [success=2 default=ignore]  pam_unix.so nullok
auth    [success=1 default=ignore]  pam_sss.so use_first_pass
auth    requisite           pam_deny.so
auth    required            pam_permit.so
auth    optional            pam_cap.so

The first line means: if the user is listed in /etc/passwd (i.e. a local account), then set the overall result tentatively to PAM_SUCCESS and proceed to the next line. Otherwise don't adjust the overall result from what it was before, and jump over next 4 lines. As a result, for a non-local user, the next line will be pam_cap.so, which is optional and the last one, so the authentication attempt will have passed through the entire auth phase without any actual authentication at all.
This matches what you're experiencing, and seems like a clear misconfiguration. You should probably comment out the pam_localuser.so line, and then try and find out the reason why it was added. If you've just blindly followed some instructions you found on the internet, you should treat those instructions as unreliable. In general, never apply any configuration you don't understand yourself first.
The rest of the auth   lines seem reasonable: both pam_unix.so (local authentication) and pam_sss.so (AD authentication) will on successful authentication skip over the unconditional rejection of the pam_deny.so, landing into pam_permit.so which will then mark the entire authentication process as successful.
It's a Friday night and I might need more caffeine, but it also seems to me that the pam_faillock.so configuration in the common-account file is incomplete: it would seem to only take effect on AD accounts, and might not correctly count failed logins anyway, as only the part of the configuration that resets the fail counter on a successful login is present. See man pam_faillock for examples on correct setup.
Note: be very careful when editing the common-auth file! If you make a typo, the worst case is that anything requiring authentication will stop working, and you'll have to boot the system using a live boot media to fix your mistake.
After making your edits and saving them but before exiting the editor, you probably should test your changes by using a second terminal window or virtual console to make a second connection to the system, and verifying that both a local and an AD-based user will be able to successfully authenticate, and that a password is actually requested from both of them.

Thank you @telcoM. Commenting out the pam_localuser.so line does seem to have brought the authentication behavior back into line with expectations. This system was built from an image that likely had some customized pam modules applied and did not take into account the alternative auth scheme I am using here. Appreciate the detailed response!
